# Android: Corrupted characters in PDF

Tags: java, android, android-file

I'm using `HttpURLConnection` to get a PDF file from the server then saving that PDF to the user's phone. Getting the file is working perfectly, but when saving, ***some*** files contain corrupted characters.

```
InputStream in = null;
OutputStream fileOutput = null;
try {
    File file = new File(path);
    file.mkdirs();
    file = new File(path + File.separator + fileName + "." + fileExentsion);
    file.createNewFile();      
    fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);
    final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int read;
    in = conn.getInputStream();
    while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
           fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
    fileOutput.flush();   
    return Uri.fromFile(file).toString(); // To open an intent in onPostExecute()
}
```

I tried using `BufferedReader` and `BufferedWriter` but the OS couldn't open the file after being saved. It is really weird because the same strings appears in other files correctly. And when downloading the file from a desktop, it looks good too.

Comment: If you download the same PDF onto the phone in a different way - e.g. just in a web browser - does *that* work? If not, then it's clearly not your code, and is probably just the PDF renderer.

Comment: @JonSkeet It is not possible to download it from external browser because of authentication restrictions

Comment: Maybe not from the exact same place, but you could put it somewhere else - or just email it to yourself and download it from your email. Or transfer it over USB. If you're saying there's no way of getting the file onto your device other than through your code, I don't believe you.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm currently working on the INT environment, INT needs a parameter to allow access, and I can't set this parameter when opening a normal browser. PS. My app uses a WebView. However, I tried to upload the downloaded pdf from my phone to google drive and still the same problem

Comment: I've no idea what you mean by "the INT environment" but I'm saying that you're able to download the file to your computer - you must be able to find a way of transferring it to your phone without using your code.

Comment: @JonSkeet I sent the file from my desktop (looks good there) to my phone and it is corrupted!!

Comment: Right, therefore it's the PDF viewer, not your code. The file itself isn't corrupted, by the sounds of it - you just can't view it with that viewer. Try other viewers.